# innerHTML or jquery.html() API isnt working for multiple search records

Tags: search, innerhtml

Long time reader. First time asking questions. I've learnt a huge amount from this forum..

I am using an online database (Caspio.com) and have configured it to return search results. Basically my database has a field "Membership" which can have 3 levels - Basic, Pro and Premium. Depending on level of membership I need to display a different HTML code in my search results page.

I've tried both 
a) Jquery's html() API

```
<div id="biz-name"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var membership = '[@field:Membership]';
if (membership == 'Basic') 
{
   $("#biz-name").html("[@field:Company_name]");
}
</script>
```

b) innerHTML

```
<div id="biz-name"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var membership = '[@field:Membership]';
if (membership == 'Basic') 
{
   document.getElementById('biz-name').innerHTML ='[@field:Company_name]';
}
</script>
```

In both cases, when the search returns multiple results, *ONLY* the 1st result's div is updated. However it has the value of the *LAST* result's Company_name.

Does anyone know how to tweak this to make it work on a per-result basis?

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I tink it's not good to have multiple elements with same id attribute. Have you tried using a class? Have you tried using the each() function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand how you would like to show the results, but I think it's not good to use the same ID attribute for multiple elements. 
Try to use class instead. Also, when you manipulate multiple results in such way I think you need to use the each() function.

```
$(".biz-name").each(function() { $(this).html("...") });
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Zoltan! Unfortunately it didnt quite work. Not sure why.. So I tried to use document.write("...") and that works!      <script>
var membership = '[@field:Membership]';
if (membership == 'Basic') 
{
document.write("<span id=\"biz-name\">[@field:Company_name]</span>");
}
</script>

Comment: I know that document.write() is generally frowned upon. So even though it works, I would appreciate if there's a suggestion for a better solution.